# How do I edit data in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-applications

I'm pretty new to angular and really struggling with understanding the syntaxes for $http.get and $http.get. What I want to do is change the data in my JSON file when the user leaves a rating in the upvote/downvote system  in the bottom of [my web app](https://ad667068912adccb975eee14116cefd5fb123f74.googledrive.com/host/0B_tg4it67g1bWWFHV3hnaXVEcGs/). The relevant part of my current code is under:

**app.js**

```
.controller('rateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('rating.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.likes = data.likes;
      $scope.dislikes = data.dislikes;
      $scope.addLike = function () {
          $scope.likes = $scope.likes + 1;
          data.likes = data.likes + 1;
      };
      $scope.addDislike = function () {
          $scope.dislikes = $scope.dislikes + 1;
          data.likes = data.likes + 1;
      };
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="content" id="sub-section">
  <div class="text-area">
      <div class="text" style="color:#3A3A3A">
          Text ...
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div>
      <table style="text-align:center; font-size:1em" class="table-responsive table" ng-controller="rateCtrl">
          <tr>
              <td>Jeg likte den!</td>
              <td>Jeg likte den ikke!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><p class="likes" ng-click="addLike()">+{{likes}}</p></td>
              <td><p class="dislikes" ng-click="addDislike()">-{{dislikes}}</p></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

**rating.json**

```
{
"likes": 12,
"dislikes": 0
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a code example for how I can change the amount of likes in the JSON file when a user likes, and vice versa for dislikes.

Comment: You can't do this from Angular. You would need to write a server to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this from the client side yet rather from the server. What you would need to do is read data from the json file. This data will be stored under `data`. From then you can `JSON.parse` it into an object. From then treat it like a regular object, and alter it. Then you must `JSON.parse` it and update your file. Sorry for putting everything in a paragraph. I am on a mobile.

Comment: I'm very new to coding, so I'm not familiar with the terms "client side" and "server side".

Comment: client side is the code that can be seen and altered by the user. It is anything that is sent to the browser and processed on the browser. Browser code isn't safe code. Server side code on the other hand is, code hosted on the computer that is running your website. It can read files off the computer, delete files, etc. If the client side was able to delete files it would cause havoc. Regular users would be deleting facebooks databases, or your json file, etc...

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to do a post. If you have a server side logic, then the proper method for that in angular is $http.post():

A snippet from the angular docs:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I do not have any server side logic (as far as I'm concerned), but I would gladly set it up with some advice!

Comment: you probably need to check out some mean stack crud tutorials online.

Comment: check this... https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application